# Alfresco tomcat hangs during startup

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I have more or less the same problem as [this person](http://forums.alfresco.com/forum/installation-upgrades-configuration-integration/installation-upgrades/34c-hangs-during-startup#comment-133735). With the exception that open/libreoffice is disabled. I have tried the bin install as well as a fresh tomcat install. All exhibit the same issue. I already had the repo instance running before hand but decided to re-install afresh as the wcmqs addon wouldn't work, since then I haven't been able to get an instance going. What else I can add is that I did notice that tomcat hangs with the CPU at 100% when I do a top inspection. There're no errors in catalina.out and this is the end of that log:

```
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,348  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default]
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,532  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'imap' subsystem, ID: [imap, default] complete
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,532  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound]
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,557  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, outbound] complete
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,557  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound]
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,612  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'email' subsystem, ID: [email, inbound] complete
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,612  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'googledocs' subsystem, ID: [googledocs, default]
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,641  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'googledocs' subsystem, ID: [googledocs, default] complete
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,641  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default]
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,648  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'Subscriptions' subsystem, ID: [Subscriptions, default] complete
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,648  INFO  [repo.usage.UserUsageTrackingComponent] [localhost-startStop-1] Disabled - clear non-missing user usages ...
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,651  INFO  [repo.usage.UserUsageTrackingComponent] [localhost-startStop-1] Found 0 users to clear
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,652  INFO  [repo.usage.UserUsageTrackingComponent] [localhost-startStop-1] ... cleared non-missing usages for 0 users
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,652  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default]
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,780  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'Synchronization' subsystem, ID: [Synchronization, default] complete
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,823  INFO  [service.descriptor.DescriptorService] [localhost-startStop-1] Alfresco JVM - v1.7.0_21-b11; maximum heap size 1460,563MB
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,824  INFO  [service.descriptor.DescriptorService] [localhost-startStop-1] Alfresco started (Community). Current version: 4.2.0 (4576) schema 6 022. Originally installed version: 4.2.0 (4576) schema 6 022.
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,824  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'ActivitiesFeed' subsystem, ID: [ActivitiesFeed, default]
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,870  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'ActivitiesFeed' subsystem, ID: [ActivitiesFeed, default] complete
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,870  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Starting 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default]
 2013-05-05 01:27:28,877  INFO  [management.subsystems.ChildApplicationContextFactory] [localhost-startStop-1] Startup of 'Replication' subsystem, ID: [Replication, default] complete
 2013-05-05 01:27:30,070  DEBUG [alfresco.repo.workflow] [localhost-startStop-1] Attached JBPM Context to transaction dba830e8-cc35-4845-bd19-d4816a1a9790
 2013-05-05 01:27:30,085  DEBUG [alfresco.repo.workflow] [localhost-startStop-1] Workflow deployer: Definition 'alfresco/workflow/publish_web_content_processdefinition.xml' already deployed
 2013-05-05 01:27:30,088  DEBUG [alfresco.repo.workflow] [localhost-startStop-1] Workflow deployer: Definition 'alfresco/workflow/publish-web-content.bpmn20.xml' already deployed
 2013-05-05 01:27:30,088  DEBUG [alfresco.repo.workflow] [localhost-startStop-1] Detached (commit) JBPM Context from transaction dba830e8-cc35-4845-bd19-d4816a1a9790
 2013-05-05 01:28:00,101  WARN  [alfresco.util.OpenOfficeConnectionTester] [DefaultScheduler_Worker-8] Error trying to query Open Office version information. OpenOffice.org's ConfigurationRegistry not implemented in this version of OOo. This should not affect the operation of OOo.
 2013-05-05 01:28:00,102  INFO  [alfresco.util.OpenOfficeConnectionTester] [DefaultScheduler_Worker-8] The OpenOffice connection was re-established.
 2013-05-05 01:30:55,814  ERROR [alfresco.util.SocketOpenOfficeConnection] [MessageDispatcher] disconnected unexpectedly
 2013-05-05 01:31:00,001  ERROR [alfresco.util.OpenOfficeConnectionTester] [DefaultScheduler_Worker-7] The OpenOffice connection has been lost.
```

I have no idea what else I can do to troubleshoot the issue.

**UPDATE**: I installed a repo on my local machine (OSX 10.7.5) and the system exhibits the same symptoms, which the processor being thrashed, but after about almost 30 mins the repo tomcat eventually starts up.

Comment: are you pointing to the correct location of  openoffice.ext file in your alfresco-global.properties file and make sure it is running.

Comment: Did you try clearing out your database and data directory to ensure a fresh install? (Possibly important if you have downgraded in your attempts)

Comment: @mitpatoliya I have ooo.enabled is set to false. I would imagine it would require that but I will check. I still however doubt this to the issue as The bin install exhibits the exact same problem and an installation on my osx is now exhibiting the same issue.

Comment: I would also try setting `ooo.exe` to a made-up value, this will definitely ensure that OpenOffice does not start

Comment: Still hangs during startup. I will also add that I started the repo on my osx earlier and the issue seems to have resolved itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that there was an issue with something in the extension path. Wiping the shared/classes/alfresco/extension folder and copying over the one from my working repo made it start. Nothing was showing up in the error or debugging information so there's no way I can really say what caused this weird issue.